# Derivative of function in tangent space of sphere

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, spheres

I have the sphere manifold $M$ with dimension n and a function $\hat{f}_x : T_x M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is defined by $\hat{f}_x (v) = f ( exp_x(v))$, where exp is the exponential map from $T_x M$ to $M$ at a point $x \in M$. $T_x M$ is the tangent space at a point $x.$

$f(y)$ is defined by $y^T A y$ for a positive definite symmetric matrix (so $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) and a point $y \in M$, and the exponential map is given by $x * cos(\|v\|_2)+v*\frac{sin(\|v\|_2)}{\|v\|_2}$ for $x \in M, v \in T_x M$.

I am trying to find the derivative of $\hat{f}$ in terms of v.
I tried deriving it by the common rules, but that doesn't work, since I need to take into account which space the functions are in. Can anybody tell me how to take on this problem?

Comment: In the hope it helps: As written, $x$ denotes at least two distinct things, a selected point of tangency and the variable in $f$. Maybe first write $f(y) = y^TAy$, then expand $f(y)$ in terms of $x$ and $v$?

Comment: I changed it, hopefully it's clearer now :)

Comment: The clarity is for _your_ benefit. :) <> When you expand $\hat{f}(y)$ in terms of ($x$ and) $v$ and differentiate, is it just that you get a large, messy expression? And maybe apropos of nothing, have you recently learned Lagrange multipliers, and/or do you need to evaluate the derivative of $\hat{f}$ only at $x$ (i.e., at $v = 0$), or generally?